# How to check for updates of sideloaded apps

Tags: google-play-store, updates, rom-flashing, backup, side-loading

And if possible also check if there is a beta/orevennewer version of the app.

I often flash new rom or restore and I have to use a backup application to restore apps and other things(The best I know about is Titanium Backup Pro, support the dev!) and most of the apps never appear in playstore's my apps list (even after using Titanium's market doctor feature) but when I search for the app play store shows I have the app installed and even that the app needs an update!

There are some Third Party markets but they often dont have the latest version and may possibly be infected with malware

**So how to check for updates?**

Comment: Are all these sideloaded apps backedup via TB Pro?

Comment: Mostly from Titanium's backup, or from Recovery by using Titanium's restore from recovery option.The exception is when there is a newer version I haven't backed up then I downlaod it from the play store IF I have the option at the time.If not (google play store  doesnt download on reverse tethering) then I use something like Aptoide